# Installing pandas from PyCharm - how do I apply a correct convention and what are the steps then?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

Had to reinstall my W machine, now fighting to come back to install modules in support of Python 3.7. Pls, someone tell me the convention (used 'pip install pandas') in a new file in PyCharm. Also, and before making the attempt in PyCharm, I attempted a simple cmd, typing the above, but my machine does not recognise 'pip'. I have a lot of files from another project based on pandas that I cannot execute because of the aforementioned issue. Can someone assist me in succeeding?

In cmd

```
C:\Users\jcst>pip install pandas
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\jcst>
```

In PyCharm

```
    pip install pandas
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

All code as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned that you have a fresh install of windows, please make sure that the python environment variables are set correctly.

In PyCharm you can install packages from Settings/Preferences. First you select your python interpreter, then you can select the packages that you want to install. For more info please refer to the official pycharm [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html).

Comment: Excellent. P3.7 was there already. Just needed to know the steps, all working now. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass environment variables and go straight to the python dir
For example: (Change python37 to your python dir)

cmd:

```
cd C:\python37\Scripts
pip install pandas
```

Note you might need to add --user to install:

```
pip install pandas --user
```